# setInterval stops working in safari browser when date changes

Tags: javascript, safari, setinterval

For example when date changes from 31 to 1 setInterval javascript function stops working when using safari browser, any ideas on workaround this problem.

How to reproduce: Create empty html with setInterval than shows some alert open safari browser change the computer date backwards (by opening your windows date/time dialog) and you'll see that timer stops working.

Comment: How are you calling your setInterval function? It's likely to be a code problem over a browser problem, really.

Comment: setInterval('getData()',5000);

Comment: Agreed dude you need to include some code and provide a way for people to reproduce this.

Comment: @user1021871 please update your question with a code sample that we can use to **reproduce the issue**.

Comment: wait - so its not about the date, your saying if you start setinterval going, then change the clock time backwards, it takes longer to get called?

Comment: So this only happens on Windows?

Comment: I can't repro this here at all http://jsfiddle.net/7Uxkh/

Answer (score 0):

There are thorough guidelines for submitting bug reports for Chrome and Webkit browsers (including Safari), which you can follow if you indeed believe you have found a bug http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines#TOC-Filing-Chromium-bugs-at-bugs.webkit.org

A simple search through the [webkit bug list](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__&product=&content=setInterval) shows no obvious bugs that have been recorded previously recorded about this issue, so I doubt it's a real thing.

Also, how are you changing computers date with JS? I think you're not understanding how the `Date` object works? You can instantiate a date instance and set its date, but not set the computers date. Again without seeing your code its super unclear how to help, sorry! May update after I see more code examples and can try to verify this "bug".

Comment: I think OP is changing the system time manually through system settings.